# Compile Error, Next without for

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to writing code in excel vba and I am receiving the compile error Next Without For.....however I have a for and a next, could you please tell me what I am doing wrong, please see my code below, thanks!

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 19 To 49

    If Cells(3, i) > 499999 Then
        Cells(4, 3) = 499999
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) < 499999 Then
        Cells(4, 3) = Cells(3, i)
    End If

    If Cells(4, 3) < 499999 Then
         Cells(4, 5) = 0
    If Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then
        Cells(4, 4) = 500000
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) < 999999 Then
        Cells(4, 4) = Cells(3, i) - 499999
    End If

    If Cells(4, 4) = 0 Then
         Cells(4, 5) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) > 1999999 Then
        Cells(4, 5) = 1000000
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) < 1999999 Then
        Cells(4, 5) = Cells(3, i) - 999999
    End If

    If Cells(4, 5) = 0 Then
         Cells(4, 6) = 0
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) > 4999999 Then
         Cells(4, 6) = 3000000
    ElseIf Cells(3, i) < 4999999 Then
        Cells(4, 6) = Cells(3, i) - 1999999
    End If

    If Cells(4, 6) = 3000000 Then
         Cells(4, 7) = Cells(3, i) - 4999999
    ElseIf Cells(4, 6) < 3000000 Then
         Cells(4, 7) = 0
    End If

    Range(7, i).Value = (Cells(5, 3) + Cells(5, 4) + Cells(5, 5) + Cells(5, 6) + Cells(5, 7)) / Cells(3, i)

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Typo: `If Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then` should be `ElseIf Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then`

Comment: Tips: Next time, comment out all the if statements, then un-comment one if block at a time until you find the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second `If` block, replace

```
If Cells(4, 3) < 499999 Then
     Cells(4, 5) = 0
If Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then
```

with

```
If Cells(4, 3) < 499999 Then
     Cells(4, 5) = 0
ElseIf Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then
```

This is what is confusing the VBA interpreter.

Comment: as i was writing the same thing Lol

Answer (score 2):

```
 If Cells(4, 3) < 499999 Then
      Cells(4, 5) = 0
 If Cells(3, i) > 999999 Then *****needs to elseif
     Cells(4, 4) = 500000
 ElseIf Cells(3, i) < 999999 Then
     Cells(4, 4) = Cells(3, i) - 499999
 End If
```

You get a type mismatch with your code in the last If blcok